# Multiple Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int _{ 5 }^{ 20 }{ \int _{ 5 }^{ 20 }{ \int _{ 5 }^{ 20 }{ \int _{ 5 }^{ 20 }{ \ln(w+x+y+z) }\ dw\; dx\; dy\; dz } } }$$

Unfortunately I cannot think of how to approach this problem. The only thing I thought was perhaps evaluating each and every integral, something which would become extremely tedious. In other words, I'm completely stumped.
$$$$I would be truly grateful if somebody would kindly show me how to solve this problem. Any help on solving this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5):

This integral is a complicated one to be sure. Because of its nature, you are probably right about having to evaluate each integral one at a time. Fortuantely, each of the four integrands breaks up in to a sum of pieces that take the form $x^n\ln(x)$. Here's a hint:

**Hint:**
given $n\geq 0$,
$$\int x^n\ln(x)dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\ln(x)-\frac{1}{n+1}\int x^n dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\ln(x)-\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}.$$

**First Few Steps**

First, we'll do the $w$ integral:
$$\int_5^{20}\ln(w+x+y+z)\,dw.$$
Let $u=w+x+y+z$. Then $du=dw$ and the limits are $5+x+y+z$ and $20+x+y+z$. This gives us the integral
$$\int_{5+x+y+z}^{20+x+y+z}\ln(u)du=u\ln(u)-u\Big|_{5+x+y+z}^{20+x+y+z}\\=(20+x+y+z)\ln(20+x+y+z)-(20+x+y+z)-(5+x+y+z)\ln(5+x+y+z)+(5+x+y+z)\\=(20+x+y+z)\ln(20+x+y+z)-(5+x+y+z)\ln(5+x+y+z)-15.$$
So you can see that the second integral is going to break up into several integrals, each of which has the form given in the hint.

The second integral is in $x$.

$$\int_5^{20}(20+x+y+z)\ln(20+x+y+z)\,dx-\int_5^{20}(5+x+y+z)\ln(5+x+y+z)\,dx-\int^{20}_5 15\,dx.$$

Letting $u=20+x+y+z$ and $v=5+x+y+z$, and evaluating the last of these terms directly, we get:

$$\int_{25+y+z}^{40+y+z}u\ln(u)\,du-\int_{10+y+z}^{25+y+z}v\ln(v)\,dv-225.$$

This evaluates to

$$u^2\ln(u)/2-u^2/4\Big|_{25+y+z}^{40+y+z}-v^2\ln(v)/2-u^2/4\Big|_{10+y+z}^{25+y+z}-225=\frac{(40+y+z)^2\ln(40+y+z)+(10+y+z)^2\ln(10+y+z)}{2}\\-(25+y+z)^2\ln(25+y+z)+\frac{(25+y+z)^2-(40+y+z)^2}{4}-225.$$

The third integral is in $y$. It consists of five terms which I will call $A_1-A_5$ and which I will calculate one at a time.

$$A_1=\frac{1}{2}\int_5^{20}(40+y+z)\ln(40+y+z)\,dy=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{(40+y+z)^3}{3}\ln(40+y+z)-\frac{(40+y+z)^3}{9}\right]_5^{20}\\=\frac{1}{6}\left((60+z)^3\ln(60+z)-(45+z)^3\ln(45+z)+\frac{(45+z)^3-(60+z)^3}{3}\right).$$

$$A_2=\frac{1}{2}\int_5^{20}(10+y+z)\ln(10+y+z)\,dy=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{(10+y+z)^3}{3}\ln(10+y+z)-\frac{(10+y+z)^3}{9}\right]_5^{20}\\=\frac{1}{6}\left((30+z)^3\ln(30+z)-(15+z)^3\ln(15+z)+\frac{(15+z)^3-(30+z)^3}{3}\right).$$

$$A_3=-\int_5^{20}(25+y+z)\ln(25+y+z)\,dy=-\left[\frac{(25+y+z)^3}{3}\ln(25+y+z)-\frac{(25+y+z)^3}{9}\right]_5^{20}\\=\frac{-1}{3}\left((45+z)^3\ln(45+z)-(30+z)^3\ln(30+z)+\frac{(30+z)^3-(45+z)^3}{3}\right).$$

$$A_4=\int_5^{20}\frac{(25+y+z)^2-(40+y+z)^2}{4}\,dy=\left[\frac{(25+y+z)^3-(40+y+z)^3}{12}\right]_5^{20}\\=\frac{2(45+z)^3-(60+z)^3-(30+z)^3}{12}.$$

$$A_5=-\int_5^{20}225\,dy=-15^3.$$

For the last integral, we will integrate each of $A_1-A_5$ and then sum them. We notice that $A_1-A_3$ all have a similar form, so we will find the general solution to

$$B(a)=\int_5^{20}(a+15+z)^3\ln(a+15+z)-(a+z)^3\ln(a+z)+\frac{(a+z)^3-(a+15+z)^3}{3}\\=\frac{1}{4}\left[(a+15+z)^4\ln(a+15+z)-(a+z)^4\ln(a+z)+5\frac{(a+z)^4-(a+15+z)^4}{6}\right]_5^{20}\\=\frac{1}{4}\left((a+35)^4\ln(a+35)-2(a+20)^4\ln(a+20)+(a+5)^4\ln(a+5)-5\frac{(a+35)^4-2(a+20)^4+(a+5)^4}{6}\right)$$

Thus,
$$B_1=\int_5^{20} A_1\,dz=\frac{1}{6}B(45)\\=\frac{1}{24}\left(80^4\ln(80)-2\times 65^4\ln(65)+50^4\ln(50)-5\frac{80^4-2\times 65^4+50^4}{6}\right).$$

$$B_2=\int_5^{20} A_2\,dz=\frac{1}{6}B(15)\\=\frac{1}{24}\left(50^4\ln(50)-2\times 35^4\ln(35)+20^4\ln(20)-5\frac{50^4-2\times 35^4+20^4}{6}\right).$$

$$B_3=\int_5^{20} A_3\,dz=-\frac{1}{3}B(30)\\=-\frac{1}{12}\left(65^4\ln(50)-2\times 50^4\ln(50)+35^4\ln(35)-5\frac{65^4-2\times 50^4+35^4}{6}\right).$$

We sum the $B_i$ for $1\leq i\leq 3$.

$$B_1+B_2+B_3=\\ \frac{1}{24}\left(80^4\ln(80)-4\times 65^4\ln(65)+6\times 50^4\ln(50)-4\times 35^4\ln(35)+20^4\ln(20)-5\frac{80^4-4\times 65^4+6\times 50^4-4\times 35^4+20^4}{6}\right).$$

One of the properties of $\ln$ is that $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b).$ Using this we can simplify the above expression:

$$B_1+B_2+B_3=\frac{1}{24}\left((4\times 80^4+6\times 50^4+2\times 20^4)\ln 2+(80^4-4\times 65^4+12\times 50^4-4\times 35^4+20^4)\ln 5-4\times 35^4\ln 7-4\times 65^4\ln 13-5\frac{80^4-4\times 65^4+6\times 50^4-4\times 35^4+20^4}{6}\right)\\=\frac{1}{6}\left(50415000\ln 2+9678750\ln 5-1500625\ln 7-17850625\ln 13-253125\right).$$

Now for $B_4$.

$$B_4=\int_5^{20}A_4\,dz=\int_5^{20}\frac{2(45+z)^3-(60+z)^3-(30+z)^3}{12}\,dz=\left[\frac{2(45+z)^4-(60+z)^4-(30+z)^4}{48}\right]_5^{20}=\frac{2\times 65^4-80^4-50^4-2\times 50^4+65^4+35^4}{48}=\frac{3\times 65^4-80^4-3\times 50^4+35^4}{48}=-\frac{388125}{4}.$$

Finally,

$$B_5=-15^4.$$

Putting it all together,

$$B_1+B_2+B_3+B_4+B_5=\\ \frac{1}{6}\left(50415000\ln 2+9678750\ln 5-1500625\ln 7-17850625\ln 13\right)-\frac{421875}{4}.$$

Comment: Sorry Sir, but I couldn't quite understand. This is the first question I'm doing on Multiple Integrals and so am quite confused. Please could you elaborate a bit and if possible, show a couple of the steps? Also Sir, could we perhaps apply Fubini's theorem for this question?

Comment: Fubini's Theorem would be helpful if either (a) we could decouple this into four individual integrals and evaluate each one (or if we are lucky, they are all the same!) or (b) if by exchanging the order of integration, it becomes simpler. We cannot do (a) because the the properties of $\ln$ do not allow us to split this into a multiplicative function. We cannot do (b) because Each integral is exactly the same. I will get back to you in a few minutes with some more steps.

Comment: Ok, I have given the first few steps. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks very much Sir.  Sir, I'm trying to understand, but I'll have to go to bed in about 15 minutes. Sir, if I don't understand some parts even now (although from how well you've explained everything, I don't think that could happen), is it alright if I ask you later on?

Comment: Till then, goodnight Sir.

Comment: Sure, let me know.

Comment: @AlexS Hullo Sir. Sir, I've been trying this problem and have really been struggling with the computations of the third and fourth integrals. I managed to solve the fist two in the same way you did. Sir, please could you show me what to do if it's not too much trouble?

Comment: I added the last few steps. It was a ton of work, so I'd appreciate the upvote/answer accept.

Comment: @AlexS Sir, I'm truly sorry but I'm not a registered user; my parents are against me signing up onto any online forum. But I'll definitely ask a friend of mine to upvote this answer.